# Auto-updating statuslines of inactive windows

Tags: statusline

When a variable on which a statusline depends changes, I see the result only in statuslines of active windows.  Can inactive ones be made to see those changes too?

Comment: Nothing happens in an *inactive* window so there's no reason for the status line of an inactive window to change.

Comment: @romainl true, but things might happen outside: a git repo might no longer have modifications, a file might have been changed externally, etc.

Comment: @muru, all things that have nothing to do with the status of the current window/buffer.

Comment: @romainl so? The inactive window can have status lines.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As @Christian Brabandt mentioned in this [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/autoupdating-statuslines-of-inactive-windows#comment12293_7484), the Ex command `:redrawstatus` does the same thing as the `'readonly'` hack, and is probably even better. From `:help redraws`:

```
                        *:redraws* *:redrawstatus*
:redraws[tatus][!]  Redraw the status line of the current window.  When !
            is included all status lines are redrawn.
            Useful to update the status line(s) when 'statusline'
            includes an item that doesn't cause automatic
            updating.
```

So, after assigning a new value to your variable you could add `| redraws!` like this:

```
:let g:myvar='bar' | redraws!
```

The bang is necessary to update all the status lines, and not just the one of the current window.

---

I don't know why but it seems that setting the value of the `'readonly'` option has also the side-effect of updating the status lines.

In `:help 'statusline'`, they mention this:

```
If the statusline is not updated when you want it (e.g., after setting
a variable that's used in an expression), you can force an update by
setting an option without changing its value.  Example: >
    :let &ro = &ro
```

So, suppose you have a variable `g:myvar` whose value is `'foo'` and appears in your status line:

```
let g:myvar='foo'
set stl+=%{g:myvar}
```

And you want to change its value to `'bar'` as well as the change to be reflected in every status line. Maybe you could type:

```
:let g:myvar='bar' | let &l:ro = &l:ro
```

(`&l:ro` is the local-buffer value of `'readonly'`)

To make it a little easier, you could install a custom command:

```
command! -nargs=1 Let exe 'let ' . <q-args> | let &l:ro = &l:ro
```

And then, type:

```
:Let g:myvar='bar'
```

Alternatively, you could remap `<CR>` in command-line mode to parse the command before its execution, check whether it matches a certain pattern (`let one_of_your_vars=`), and substitute the end of the command to add `| let &l:ro = &l:ro`.

Comment: there is also the ":redrawstatus" command.